# How can I delete a Python-Tkinter def LabelFrame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using buttons to call def variables that create labelframes. I'm switching between the buttons like tabs and want to display my new frames underneath respectively yet the old labelframe is left behind and is not defined to be called for erasing.

Here's an example of how i'm phrasing the code.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.state('zoomed')

def A1():
    lf=LabelFrame(root,text='new frame')
    lf.pack()
    d=Button(lf, text='Added', width=0, borderwidth=3)
    d.pack()

a = Button(root, text="add", command=A1)
a.pack()
b=Button(root,text="Delete me",command=lambda:b.pack_forget())
b.pack()
c=Button(root,text="Delete Added",command=lambda:lf.pack_forget())
c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you for your time and advice.

Comment: and what is your problem here?

Comment: You should get `NameError: name 'lf' is not defined` when you click `Delete Added` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

- Make a function to delete the frame.
- Create the button with no command initially.
- Set the button's command when the frame is created.
- Then, when the frame is deleted, reset the button's command.

Such as this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.state('zoomed')

# Added a function to delete the frame and reset the button's command
def remove_frame(lf):
    lf.pack_forget()
    c.config(command=None)

def A1():
    lf=LabelFrame(root,text='new frame')
    lf.pack()
    d=Button(lf, text='Added', width=0, borderwidth=3)
    d.pack()

    # Sets the remove_frame function to the button's command.
    # Since lf is created locally it will need to be passed to the remove_frame function.
    c.config(command=lambda: remove_frame(lf))

a = Button(root, text="add", command=A1)
a.pack()
b=Button(root,text="Delete me",command=lambda:b.pack_forget())
b.pack()
c=Button(root,text="Delete Added") # Create the button with no command.
c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Currently this will allow you to add several frames, but only delete one.

If the goal is to only have one frame, disabling the add button until the frame is deleted would be the easiest option.

If you wanted to delete them sequentially or all of them, appending the frames to a `list` and using a `pack_forget` on each item in the list would be one method of accomplishing this.

Comment: I'm incredibly impressed by how well you answered that. Thank you sincerely for this solution.